# problems converting code from another language

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am attempting to convert this code ([Code pen](https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/WyNdMG?fbclid=IwAR1fEEF016k-yzXg0eMShVu_ECBfGCH0vDmGF37eiAxUNm2q4V_9Mkdyjeg)) into my react JavaScript code, but I am failing, probably not least because I don't know what language the original code is in!

This is as far as I've got:

index.js:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout'
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css'
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/posts'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Date from '../components/date'
import react from 'react'

export default function Home({ allPostsData }) {
  return (
    statics: {
      droplets = 250
      rain
        - for (let r = 0; r < droplets; r++)- const droplets = 250
      rain
        - for (let r = 0; r < droplets; r++)
    }
    <Layout home>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
       svg.rain__drop(preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin", viewBox='0 0 5 50', style=`--x: 
        ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; --y: 
        ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; --o: 
        ${Math.random()}; --a: ${Math.random() + 0.5}; --d: 
        ${(Math.random() * 2) - 1}; --s: ${Math.random()}`)
      path(stroke='none', d="M 2.5,0 C 2.6949458,3.5392017 3.344765,20.524571 4.4494577,30.9559 5.7551357,42.666753 4.5915685,50 2.5,50 0.40843152,50 -0.75513565,42.666753 0.55054234,30.9559 1.655235,20.524571 2.3050542,3.5392017 2.5,0 Z")
            
      <section className={utilStyles.headingMd}>
        <p>'Very capable, friendly individual. Have been off work due to illness and have recently got back into
the workforce and am now looking for something more challenging which would enable me to
support a family. I have great skills and knowledge in the hospitality sector and am also very
technologically minded. I have experience with HTML, CSS, JAVA, & other languages. I feel capable of
learning any programming language. I would like the opportunity to develop my skills and a career in
the technology sector.'
        </p>
        <p>
          (This is a sample website - you’ll be building a site like this in{' '}
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn">our Next.js tutorial</a>.)
        </p>
      </section>
      <section className={`${utilStyles.headingMd} ${utilStyles.padding1px}`}>
        <h2 className={utilStyles.headingLg}>Blog</h2>
        <ul className={utilStyles.list}>
          {allPostsData.map(({ id, date, title }) => (
            <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={id}>
              <Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
                <a>{title}</a>
              </Link>
              <br />
              <small className={utilStyles.lightText}>
                <Date dateString={date} />
              </small>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData()
  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData
    }
  }
}
```

layout.module.css:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 36rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 3rem auto 6rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.backToHome {
  margin: 3rem 0 0;
}

*
*:before
*:after
  box-sizing border-box

body
  background-color #6c78a9
  display flex
  align-items center
  justify-content center

.rain__drop
  animation-delay calc(var(--d) * 1s)
  animation-duration calc(var(--a) * 1s)
  animation-iteration-count infinite
  animation-name drop
  animation-timing-function linear
  height 30px
  left calc(var(--x) * 1%)
  position absolute
  top calc((var(--y) + 50) * -1px)

  path
    fill #808fbf
    opacity var(--o)
    transform scaleY(calc(var(--s) * 1.5))

@keyframes drop
  90%
    opacity 1
  100%
    opacity 0
    transform translateY(100vh)
```

I am sorry for being a terrible noob, but we all have to start somewhere!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much,
ClaaziX

Comment: It's pug (it says right above it). Please add some more details. What doesn't work? Where aree you stuck?

Comment: In Codepen, you can click the down arrow next to a section header and select "View Compiled (language)" for compiled languages. In this case, viewing the compiled HTML may be useful.

Comment: It's just not displaying the rain, no error messages!

Comment: oh! apart from: 

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_detection.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one to one conversion of the PUG and SCSS to vanilla JS

Just change the innerHTML= to your react element

```js
document.querySelector(".rain").innerHTML = Array.from({ length: 250 })
  .map((_, i) => `<svg class="rain__drop" preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin" viewBox = '0 0 5 50' 
style="
--x: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; 
--y: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; 
--o: ${Math.random()}; 
--a: ${Math.random() + 0.5}; 
--d: ${(Math.random() * 2) - 1}; 
--s: ${Math.random()}">
  <path stroke="none" 
    d="M 2.5,0 C 2.6949458,3.5392017 3.344765,20.524571 4.4494577,30.9559 5.7551357,42.666753 4.5915685,50 2.5,50 0.40843152,50 -0.75513565,42.666753 0.55054234,30.9559 1.655235,20.524571 2.3050542,3.5392017 2.5,0 Z"></path></svg>`).join("")
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #6c78a9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.rain__drop {
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--d) * 1s);
          animation-delay: calc(var(--d) * 1s);
  -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--a) * 1s);
          animation-duration: calc(var(--a) * 1s);
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: drop;
          animation-name: drop;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
  height: 30px;
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1%);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((var(--y) + 50) * -1px);
}
.rain__drop path {
  fill: #a1c6cc;
  opacity: var(--o);
  transform: scaleY(calc(var(--s) * 1.5));
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
}
@keyframes drop {
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rain"></div>
```

So in React I guess it would be something like

```
render() { 
   const div = `<div className="rain">
     ${Array.from({ length: 250 })
      .map((_, i) => `<svg className="rain__drop" preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin" viewBox = '0 0 5 50' 
    style="
    --x: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; 
    --y: ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}; 
    --o: ${Math.random()}; 
    --a: ${Math.random() + 0.5}; 
    --d: ${(Math.random() * 2) - 1}; 
    --s: ${Math.random()}">
      <path stroke="none" 
        d="M 2.5,0 C 2.6949458,3.5392017 3.344765,20.524571 4.4494577,30.9559 5.7551357,42.666753 4.5915685,50 2.5,50 0.40843152,50 -0.75513565,42.666753 0.55054234,30.9559 1.655235,20.524571 2.3050542,3.5392017 2.5,0 Z"></path></svg>`).join("")}
  </div>}`
   return div
};
```

Comment: That didn't work, I think I am putting this in the wrong places...could you please explain where to put the code you provided?

Comment: No. I do not do React. So you are on your own there